# How to get just the most recent of all documents

Tags: sanity, groq

In sanity studio you get a nice list of the most recent version of all your documents. If there is a draft you get that, if not, you get the published one.

I need the same list for a few filters and scripts. The following groq does the job but is not very fast and does not work in the new API (v2021-03-25).

```
*[
  _type == $type &&
  !defined(*[_id == "drafts." + ^._id])
]._id
```

A way around the breaking changes in the API is to use `length() = 0` in place of `!defined()` but that makes an already slow query 10-20 X slower.

Does anyone know a way of making filters that consider only the latest version?

> Edit: An example where I need this is if I want to see all documents without any categories. Regardless whether it is the published document or the draft that has no categories it shows up in a normal filter. So if you add categories but don't immediately want to publish it will be confusing in the no-categories-list. ,'-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**100 X improvement on API v2021-03-25**

The only way I was able to solve this with speed was to first make a projection of the sub-query so it doesn't run once for every non-draft. Then I thought, why not project both sets and then figure out the overlap, and that was even faster! It runs more than 10 x faster than possible on API v1 and 100 x faster than any suggestions for new API.

```js
{
  'drafts': *[ _type == $type && _id in path("drafts.**") ]._id,
  'published': *[ _type == $type && !(_id in path("drafts.**"))]._id,
}
{
  'current': published[ !("drafts." + @ in ^.drafts) ] + drafts
}
```

1. First I get both drafts and non-drafts and "store" it in this projection, like a variable--ish
2. Then I start with my non-drafts - `published`
3. And filter out any that has a counterpart in my `drafts` "variable"
4. Lastly I add all drafts to the my list of filtered non-drafts

Comment: This is an extremely interesting use-case of GROQ's projections, I'm amazed  Thanks for sharing, @cfm!

I hope you managed to get the structure builder part of the challenge going, feel free to follow up here or in another question if otherwise 

Comment: Yes, I think I can use this in the structure builder even though I don't have pagination. I just add my extra filters of no-categories or whatever at the end and it's less than 150 ms long. Only thing left is figuring out how to make a `S.documentList()` of my `client.fetch(API-v-new)` result.

If you think it can be useful give me som upvotes :-D

Comment: I think it'd require a list of `S.documentListItem`. Sanity will automatically load the preview for each, only when they come into view. 

Should be something like: `S.list().title("").items(async () => const ids = await client.fetch(QUERY); return ids.map(id => S.documentListItem().id(id).schemaType(SCHEMA_TYPE))`

Answer (score 1):

Overall I think you're on the right track. Some ideas to help you out:

1. Drafts are always fresher and newer than published documents, so if a given doc's `id in path("drafts.**")`, that's already the last updated one.
2. Knowing the above allows you to skip the `defined(*[_id == ...])` part of the query for drafts, speeding up your execution
3. As drafts are already included, we can exclude published documents with a draft (`defined(*[_id == "drafts." + ^._id][0])`)
4. Notice I added a `[0]` to the end of the query to pick only the first element that matches. This will improve performance slightly.
5. For getting only documents that have no categories, use `count(categoriesField) < 1`
6. Order documents with `| order(_updatedAt desc)` to get the freshest documents first
7. And paginate your request to reduce the payload and speed things up.

Here's a sample query applying these principles (I haven't ran it, you may have to do some adjustments there):

```
*[
  _type == $type &&
  // Assuming you only want those without categories:
  count(categories) < 1 &&
  (
    // Is either a draft -> drafts are always fresher
    _id in path("drafts.**") ||
    // Or a published document with no draft
    !defined(*[_id == "drafts." + ^._id][0])

    //  with the check above we're ensuring only
    // published documents run the expensive defined query
  )
]
// Order by last updated
| order(_updatedAt desc)
// Paginate for faster queries
[$paginationStart..$paginationEnd]
// Get only the _id, assuming that's what you want
._id
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you for chiming in @henrique! Yes, makes sense to _hide_ the inner query for **drafts**. And a lot of good principles in your post. Your query runs in both old and new API. However, I'm not sure how, or if I can, add pagination for a `S.documentList()` in the desk structure. And without pagination it's still too slow in the new API. The user will think the list is empty and move on.